# How to build a reinforcement learning with certain constraints on the actions

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to build a reinforcement learning algorithm for the following scheme:
There is a 2D N X N grid where each vertex of the grid can store a single particle. The particles are initially randomly distributed in the 2D grid. I have a 'picker' which grabs the particles and can move them to certain place.The goal of the algorithm is that given a target sub-area of the grid I need it to be completely filled with particles with fewest number of moves. There is a constraint for the movement of the picker, which is that the picker can grab multiple particles but it can only do so and move in one dimension at a time (one row or one column).
For example:

For a 3 x 3 grid with initially filling [[1,0,1,1],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1]] where 1 means a filled vertex and 0 is empty vertex

Then the following senarios are ***allowed***:

**1**.I can pick a row and move particles into any configuration in 1D. For example, the first row can be moved as [1,1,1,0] or [0,1,1,1]...

**2**. I can pick a column and perform same operation as step 1 except this operation is confined in column(1D) only

**3**.I can pick a row and shift the row column-wise. For example I can pick the entire 2nd row and shift it down to the third row. The final configuration would look like
[[1,0,1,1],[0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,1]]

**4**. I can also pick a column and shift the column row-wise. For example I can pick the entire 1st column and shift it right to the second column. The final configuration would look like
[[0,1,1,1],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1]]

I think for 1 particle this will just be the simple version of 'snake find the food' game. For N particles, I have couple thoughts:

1. at each move, I assign 4 possible actions to each particle so there will be 4N action in total. And I made a giant penalty for the moves that violate the allowed moves. But the biggest drawback would be that even if the network learns this rule after a long train it's still possible that it might run into this constraint during the test.
2. somehow I hardcode this constraint into actions but not sure how that can be done.

I think the first option is not what I want. For the second option, the question is how would I add the constraint to the action in this senario?

Comment: And what exactly is the question? I think I missed it somehow.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Just updated the post. The question is how would I add a specific constraint on the action?